# How to load pre-trained tensorflow model named inception by Google?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have downloaded a tensorflow checkpoint model named `inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt`.

Do I need to create a graph (with all the variables) that were used when this checkpoint was created?

How do I make use of this model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of you have get the network architecture in memory. You can get the network architecture from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py)

Once you have this program with you, use the following approach to use the model:

```
from inception_resnet_v2 import inception_resnet_v2, inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope

height = 299
width = 299
channels = 3

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels])
with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
     logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(X, num_classes=1001,is_training=False)
```

With this you have all the network in memory, Now you can initialize the network with checkpoint file(ckpt) by using tf.train.saver:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "/home/pramod/Downloads/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")
```

If you want to do bottle feature extraction, its simple like lets say you want to get features from last layer, then simply you have to declare `predictions = end_points["Logits"]` If you want to get it for other intermediate layer, you can get those names from the above program inception_resnet_v2.py

After that you can call: `output =  sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={X:batch_images})`

Comment: I think along with the ckpt file,you can also search for .meta file for that network.meta file can used to recreate the network using tf.train.import() function like this: saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('The_model.meta').

Comment: Yes, can be done.But I haven't seen .meta file for above network. If you have come across such, please comment link for the same.

Comment: tf.trainable_variables()  listed down variables of inception model too despite the fact that these are not trainable.

Comment: @AnilKumar, I have used the .meta pre-retrain file as well (found in the TF-slim github), but received this error: `ValueError: No op named SSTableReaderV2 in defined operations.` Can you let me know how do we work around this?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to create a graph (with all the variables) that were used when this checkpoint was created?

No, you don't.

As for how to use checkpoint file (cpkt file)

1.This article ([TensorFlow-Slim image classification library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/README.md)) tells you how to train your model **from scratch**

2.The following is an example code from [google blog](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/improving-inception-and-image.html)

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import urllib2

from datasets import imagenet
from nets import inception
from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing

slim = tf.contrib.slim

batch_size = 3
image_size = inception.inception_v3.default_image_size

checkpoints_dir = '/root/code/model'
checkpoints_filename = 'inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'
model_name = 'InceptionResnetV2'
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
graph = tf.Graph()
graph.as_default()

def classify_from_url(url):
    image_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    processed_image = inception_preprocessing.preprocess_image(image,     image_size, image_size, is_training=False)
processed_images  = tf.expand_dims(processed_image, 0)

# Create the model, use the default arg scope to configure the batch norm parameters.
with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception.inception_resnet_v2(processed_images, num_classes=1001, is_training=False)
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
    os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, checkpoints_filename),
    slim.get_model_variables(model_name))

init_fn(sess)
np_image, probabilities = sess.run([image, probabilities])
probabilities = probabilities[0, 0:]
sorted_inds = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(-probabilities), key=lambda x:x[1])]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np_image.astype(np.uint8))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

names = imagenet.create_readable_names_for_imagenet_labels()
for i in range(5):
    index = sorted_inds[i]
    print('Probability %0.2f%% => [%s]' % (probabilities[index], names[index]))
```

Comment: The example can also be found under using pre-trained models in the following ipython notebook: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Another way of loading a pre-trained Imagenet model is

**ResNet50**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
model = ResNet50()
model.summary()
```

**InceptionV3**

```
iport tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
model = InceptionV3()
model.summary()
```

You can check a detailed explanation related to this [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-when-developing-convolutional-neural-network-models/)